# PyQt how to make a toolbar button appeared as pressed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtoolbar

I want to make a specific button in PyQt toolbar appeared as pressed(with blue background). Suppose when I hit the toolbar button I want it to be appeared as pressed

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 700, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Rich Text Editor')
        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        changeBoldActionTB = \
        QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('bold-text-option.png'),
                      'Make the text bold', self)
        changeBoldActionTB.triggered.connect(self.changeBold)

        self.formatbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.formatbar)
        self.formatbar.addAction(changeBoldActionTB)
        self.show()

    def changeBold(self):
         pass
         #I think this does't matter        

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

I have two toolbars.I am planning to use **cursorPositionChanged** to do this but still is there a way in PyQt to do this
[image]

reproduible code:
https://files.fm/u/h4c2amdx

Comment: I want the button's background to be changed to blue.Its an image button

Comment: I want the button's background to turn to blue and it's an image button

Comment: yes I want to do that

Comment: Yes but that would require more resources but still can you show some code

Comment: yes i want to toggle between its states

Comment: To put the letter "B" are you using an image?

Comment: yes i want to use that button

Comment: actually it's already in the code

Comment: oh wait a little

Comment: Okay, I hope, but try to do the same for all your questions, helps us a lot since the community takes it as a base and we do not waste time creating everything from scratch.

Comment: wait just a little

Comment: sorry for being late https://files.fm/u/h4c2amdx

Comment: Are you working on it

Comment: try with my solution :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `QAction` you must use [`QToolButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html) and set the [`checkable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) property to True:

```
toolButton.setCheckable(True)
```

Example:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Rich Text Editor')
        self.statusBar = QStatusBar(self)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        toolButton = QToolButton(self)
        toolButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('bold-text-option.png'))
        toolButton.setCheckable(True)
        toolButton.toggled.connect(self.onToggled)

        self.formatbar = QToolBar(self)
        self.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.formatbar)
        self.formatbar.addWidget(toolButton)

    def onToggled(self, checked):
        print(checked)
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

**Plus:** To set the value manually and to obtain the status the following instructions are used:

```
toolButton.setChecked(True) # set State
print(toolButton.isChecked()) # get State
toolButton.toggle() # change state
```

Comment: One more thing can you also tell me how to see the tool button current state

Comment: Wow thats what I want.My text editor is just going on an whole other level.thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Actions also have a checable flag and they can act as a toggle switch. Sorry, I don’t know English. So I showed it with code.

```
# add this code before self.formatbar = QToolBar()
# and create img file blue_bold-text-option.png
self.changeBoldActionTB.setCheckable(True)
icon = QIcon()
icon.addFile('bold-text-option.png', QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
icon.addFile('blue_bold-text-option.png', QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.On)
self.changeBoldActionTB.setIcon(icon)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.